# Use or statement in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a `messages` table in my database and the query I want to perform is:

```
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM MESSAGES WHERE sender_id = ' . $id. ' OR receiver_id = '.  $id;
```

That is what I am looking for. So, how do I do the very same thing in laravel?
I searched in the laravel documentation and found something like `SQL raw statements` but I guess it can be vulnerable to SQL attacks, so how do I do it safely and sweetly?

Comment: I'd start with the manual https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries. Don't put variables into SQL.

Comment: @user3783243 I have already done that and I have **some** experience in Laravel.

Comment: And you saw the `You may chain where constraints together as well as add or clauses to the query. The  orWhere method accepts the same arguments as the where method:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is is the "Laravel Way" of building the raw query you've got.

```
DB::table('messages')->where('sender_id', '=', $id)
                     ->orWhere('reciever_id', '=', $id)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your may use the following code to solve your problem.

```
   DB::table('messages')
                 ->where('sender_id', $id)
                 ->orWhere('reciever_id', $id)
                 ->get();
```